# Raspberry pi development

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, iot, snapcraft

I am extremely new to IOT and have recently got myself a raspberry pi. I got Ubuntu installed on it and created a couple of snaps after connecting to ubuntu-core.
The snap which was created is a armhf.snap file. When I run the snapcraft command, it gets built fine with no errors. But when I try to install the snap on my local environment, It gives me an error saying "snap requires classic confinement which is only available on classic systems". 
I tried using sudo install snap --dangerous snap_name.snap --classic and I still get the error.
When I just run sudo install snap snap_name, I get an error saying "cannot open snap".
Can anybody help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to change the YAML confinement to devmode or strict and run `sudo snap install` with `--devmode` option.

Comment: Glad to know you did it.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your help, I had help from the snapcraft forum :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run:

```
$ sudo snap install classic --edge --devmode
$ sudo classic

Creating classic environment
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 4 processors
11111 inodes (11975 blocks) to write

[===========================================================/] 11975/11975 100%

(classic)user@localhost:~$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapcraft build-essential git
```

Comment: I have already done the above except for the build-essential install. I installed it now and tried running it, Im getting an error saying "cannot open sname_name.snap". I also have a doubt if I should install snap in the classic confinement or the local environment. I have tried both anyways.

Comment: I also started in Raspberry with Ubuntu Core (the harder way). Ubuntu Core was released in 2016 so help online is quite a scarce resource. You can access also: https://forum.snapcraft.io for answers.